# Storing data to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsuserdefaults, abrecordref

In my iPhone app, I have a class called `Contact` which consists of an `ABRecordRef` to serve as a reference to a particular contact.

I need to store groups of these contacts in `NSUserDefaults`, but things aren't working out so well since `Contact` is a custom class.

Any ideas of what to do in this case?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot use `NSUserDefaults` for a custom class. From the documentation:

> The `NSUserDefaults` class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`,
>   `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of `NSData`.

Try using `NSData`. For example, to load custom objects into an array, you can do

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"savedArray"];
if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
{
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
                objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
                objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

To archive the data, use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objectArray] forKey:@"savedArray"];
```

This will all work so long as your custom object complies with the `NSCoding` protocol:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:label forKey:@"label"];
    [coder encodeInteger:numberID forKey:@"numberID"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        label = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"label"];
        numberID = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"numberID"];
    }   
    return self;
}
```

`ABRecord` is an opaque C type, so it's not an object in the sense of Objective-C. That means you can not extend it, you can not add a category on it, you can not message it. The only thing you can do is call functions described in `ABRecord` Reference with the `ABRecord` as a parameter.

You could do two things to be able to keep the information referenced by the `ABRecord` around:

1. Get the `ABRecord`s `id` by `ABRecordGetRecordID()`. The `ABRecordID` is defined as int32_t so you can cast it to an `NSInteger` and store it wherever you like. You can later get the record back from `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID()` or `ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID()`. However, the record could be changed or even deleted by the user or another app meanwhile.
2. Copy all values inside the record to a standard `NSObject` subclass and use `NSCoding` as discussed above to store it. You will then, of course, not benefit from changes or additions to the record the user could have made.

Comment: But I can't encode ABRecordRef because it's not an object aparently.

Comment: You shouldn't start your answer by "You cannot use NSUserDefaults for a custom class". Say, "you can" or "you cannot do it out of the box but"

Answer (score 2):

Well, [Apple's recommendation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html) is to store the record identifier, the first name, and the last name. You can then try retrieving the contact from the address book by the identifier and, if the record isn't found or if it's not the right person, try retrieving by first and last name (since record identifiers may change depending on the source of your address book data).

This may or may not be what you want, depending on why you're storing the data. But, you could pretty easily put those three values into an NSDictionary and write the dictionary to `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

ABRecordRef appears to be a `const void *`, so store it in `NSUserDefaults`, you have to wrap it in `NSData` : `NSData *d = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:thePointer length:sizeof(ABRecordRef)];`.

Comment: yes, but how do I store an ABRecordRef, since it's not an object apparently

Comment: do you know at least what it is ? object, struct, base type ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it actually using conversion to vCard representation, which is CFStringRef, that can be easily used as NSString.