# NSUserDefaults Loading Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

Whenever I open my app, it doesn't load my array values because the != nil function isn't called. Is there anything I can do about this?

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var toDoData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if (toDoData.valueForKey("TDDATA") != nil){
    todos = toDoData.valueForKey("TDDATA") as! NSArray as! [TodoModel]
   }

    if todos.count != 0{
    toDoData.setValue(todos, forKeyPath: "TDDATA")
    toDoData.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the table. It populates perfectly. I just need the loading data issue fixed.

Code included in your answer helps a lot!

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Here is the TodoModel:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class TodoModel : NSObject, NSCoding {
var id: String
var image: String
var title: String
var desc: String
var scores: String


init (id: String, image: String, title: String, desc: String, scores: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.image = image
    self.title = title
    self.desc = desc
    self.scores = scores

  }

}
```

Comment: Where else do you save something to `NSUserDefaults`? This save won't execute since the count will be 0

Comment: ya i know. I just need a way of executing it without the app crashing when it loads with no data.

Comment: The code you have shown is (probably) OK, but you need to save the data somewhere when you add a new entry to your `todos` array.  I say probably because I don't know whether you have implemented NSCoding for `ToDoModel`.  You should have an `else` after your first `if` that assigns an empty array to `todos`

Comment: @AndyLebo Delete the app from the device and debug again. When you re-launch the app second time, obviously you will have some cache and it will hit your != 0 setter again. Check the logic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueForKey` and `setValue:forKeyPath` are KVC (Key Value Coding) methods (read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)). It will not help you read/write to the user defaults database.

Looking in the `NSUserDefaults` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html), there are a number of methods available for getting and setting values in the defaults database. Since you are using arrays, we will use:

- `arrayForKey` to get.
- `setObject:forKey` to set. (There is no array-specific setter)

---

EDIT: Try this in your `viewDidAppear`. Here we check if we have data, and if we do, we store it. If we don't have data, then check if the defaults database has some saved. If it does, use it instead. It would be advantageous to only load data from the defaults database in `viewDidLoad`, and then save in `viewDidAppear` or even better, a function which is called when a todo is added.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if todos.count > 0 {
        // Save what we have
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(todos)
        defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "TDDATA")
        defaults.synchronize()
        print("saved \(todos.count)")
    } else if let storedTodoData = defaults.dataForKey("TDDATA"),
        storedTodos = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(storedTodoData) as? [TodoModel] {
        // There was stored data! Use it!
        todos = storedTodos
        print("Used \(todos.count) stored todos")
    }
}
```

In addition, we must implement the `NSCoding` protocol in your model. This should be something like this:

```
class TodoModel: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var myInt: Int = 0
    var myString: String?
    var myArray: [String]?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        myInt = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("myInt")
        myString = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("myString") as? String
        myArray = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("myArray") as? [String]
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeInteger(myInt, forKey: "myInt")
        aCoder.encodeObject(myString, forKey: "myString")
        aCoder.encodeObject(myArray, forKey: "myArray")
    }
}
```

(Of course, replace myInt, myString, myArray, etc, with whatever properties your model might have.)

Comment: Also, there really isn't any reason for you to immediately save the todos to the defaults database. It would make more sense to do that after you have todos to save.

Comment: so i moved the code to viewDidAppear instead. Also, whenever I add an element in todos, I go back to this page and therefore this code. Now the problem is that when I add an element to the array, it goes back to this page and shows the new tableViewCell but then once it runs the viewDid Appear code it disappears. Probably because it loads the empty array before it saves the array. I know this is a problem but I'm still not sure how to fix it (I used your code). Help pls? Thanks

Comment: all in all, I need a way to define that toDoData goes with "TDDATA" without creating an action and i don't know how to do that. Help pls @Santa_Claus

Comment: @AndyLebo Check my updated answer. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: @Santa_Claus I ran your updated code and got a SIGABRT error. This i'm betting is because when there is no database created when todos == 0. Here is the error message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "<Challenger.TodoModel: 0x7fb88bf00a90>"
) for key TDDATA'

Comment: @Santa_Claus Is there a way to create the "TDDATA" nsuserdefaults database without linking it to an  action? Because what happens is I run it, and it crashes probably because it tries to tamper with "TDDATA" when we haven't yet said that "TDDATA" exists.

Comment: @AndyLebo Sorry, I should have caught this earlier. Instead of directly trying to save an array of TodoModel, you must archive the array to `NSData` using `NSKeyedArchiver`. I'll update my answer. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6696735/2446155)

Comment: @Santa_Claus Thanks. I clicked "this" but it was obj c so i don't really understand it well. But ya I would **greatly appreciate** it if you could update your code to your answer. Thanks for being a great help

Comment: check my updated question. I put in the todo model. Could you please try to adjust based on the todo Model because I think it's different than what you thought @Santa_Claus thanks

Comment: @AndyLebo Glad to help!