# IOS/Objective-C: Save Custom Array as NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save an array of objects into an NSUserDefault without success.  When I log out the array before the attempt it is full of object.  However, when I try to log out the NSUserDefault it is NULL.  Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks for any suggestions:

```
 Items *myItems = [mutableFetchedObjects mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"my Items%@",myItems);//LOGS OUT LONG LIST OF ITEMS
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myItems];
    [currentDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"myItems"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
    Items *myRetrievedItems = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"myItems"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"my Retrieved Items%@",myRetrievedItems); //LOGS OUT AS NULL
```

Comment: Why are you using `arrayForKey`?  You need to retrieve the data and unarchive it

Comment: I am not sure but you are logging the same object even then it is showing you NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers mentioned, it is because your array is not complying to the NSDictionary types (string, binary, bool, etc). Your members of array is of custom types therefore it cannot be saved. What you need to do is convert your array to binary first and then save it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unarchive your data first at the time of retrieving back. You are directly accessing the data. This won't work. You can do it the similar way you are archiving the data

```
NSData *dataObj = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"myItems"];

Items *myRetrievedItems = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataObj];
```

For more reference, you can consider this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6696735/3824808)

Hope this helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Got [Items initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @user6631314 as mention by iGenio, it might be because your class does not conform to NSCoding protocol. You can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6696735/3824808

Answer (score 0):

Your access value method is wrong.

You can get the array in following code:

Items *myRetrievedItems = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myItems"] mutableCopy];